# glCompressedTexSubimage2d with ETC1 texture data

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to get glCompressedTexSubimage2d with ETC1 textures to work in a OpenGL ES 3.2 context.

I know that glCompressedTexSubimage2d is specified to work with ETC2 (https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man32/html/glCompressedTexSubImage2D.xhtml) but not ETC1. However, ETC2 is defined to be backwards compatible to ETC1 (http://www.jacobstrom.com/publications/StromPetterssonGH07.pdf), so any ETC1 texture should also be a valid ETC2 texture (correct me please if I'm wrong) - so instead of GL_ETC1_RGB8_OES I am using GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2 as internal format for both the target as well as the uploaded subtexture. Both the target as well as the uploaded subtexture are multiples of 4 in each dimension and the offsets are also aligned to multiples of 4.

Yet, I'm getting an Invalid_Operation error on the call, for example with the following argumets:

```
*** GL error after call to CompressedTexSubImage2D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, level = 0, xoffset = 0, yoffset = 2048, width = 512, height = 1024, format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2, imageSize = 262144, data = 0xc13ab008): invalid operation
```

In this case the size of the compressed target texture is 1024x4096

The same code (OpenGL equivalent) works with dxt1 running on windows.

Am I correct that this should work as intended, or are there restrictions I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenGL ES 3.2 specification:

> For ETC2/EAC images GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if width is not a multiple of four, and width + xoffset is not equal to the width of the texture level; if height is not a multiple of four, and height + yoffset is not equal to the height of the texture level; or if xoffset or yoffset is not a multiple of four.

You are failing both of the "width/height + x/yoffset  == w/h of texture" constraints.

Comment: Do you know the reason for this restriction? the same restriction is stated in EXT_texture_compression_s3tc but with dxt1 on desktop it works nevertheless.

Comment: Not a clue, sorry.

Comment: Seems very weird you can only upload the lower right part of the texture

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but it seems like it could also be more of a driver bug. The previous answer seems to misinterpret the (rather confusing) requirement from the GL spec.

"GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if width is not a multiple of four, and width + xoffset is not equal to the width of the texture level;"

I believe this requirement is intended to mean that if only if the width is NOT a multiple of 4, THEN it must satisfy width + xoffset == full texture width.